# Pandas melt dataframe with multiple value columns

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I have the following dataframe:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([
    {'F1': 'a', 'F1_D': 'aa', 'F2': 'a', 'F2_D': 'aa', 'F3': 'a', 'F3_D': 'aa'},
    {'F1': 'b', 'F1_D': 'bb', 'F2': 'b', 'F2_D': 'bb', 'F3': 'b', 'F3_D': 'bb'},
    {'F1': 'c', 'F1_D': 'cc', 'F2': 'c', 'F2_D': 'cc', 'F3': 'c', 'F3_D': 'cc'},
    {'F1': 'd', 'F1_D': 'dd', 'F2': 'd', 'F2_D': 'dd', 'F3': 'd', 'F3_D': 'dd'},
])

>>>x

    F1  F1_D    F2  F2_D    F3  F3_D
0   a    aa      a   aa      a   aa
1   b    bb      b   bb      b   bb
2   c    cc      c   cc      c   cc
3   d    dd      d   dd      d   dd
```

I want to transform this dataframe to long form but have two value variables, like below:

```
col1    col2    col3
F1       a       aa
F2       a       aa 
F3       a       aa 
F1       b       bb
F2       b       bb
 .       .        .
 .       .        . 
 .       .        .
F3       d       dd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add `_col2` for columns names if not ending by `_D` in `rename`:

```
f = lambda x: f'{x}' if x.endswith('_D') else f'{x}_col2'
x = x.rename(columns=f)
print (x)
  F1_col2 F1_D F2_col2 F2_D F3_col2 F3_D
0       a   aa       a   aa       a   aa
1       b   bb       b   bb       b   bb
2       c   cc       c   cc       c   cc
3       d   dd       d   dd       d   dd
```

And then reshape by `split` with `_` and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for some data cleaning:

```
x.columns = x.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = (x.stack(0)
       .rename_axis([None, 'col1'])
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .rename(columns={'D':'col3'}))

print (df)
   col1 col3 col2
0    F1   aa    a
1    F2   aa    a
2    F3   aa    a
3    F1   bb    b
4    F2   bb    b
5    F3   bb    b
6    F1   cc    c
7    F2   cc    c
8    F3   cc    c
9    F1   dd    d
10   F2   dd    d
11   F3   dd    d
```